# Use addTarget:action:forControlEvents: method to change a UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage, uicontrol

I am intending to add a "blank" star icon on my page which will be changed to a "solid" star when a user clicks on it.

I tried to set the `UIImage` as shown below:

```
UIImage *hotIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_star.png"];
```

Can anyone advise me how I can use the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method? Can I even use this method on a `UIImage`? Or must I definitely use a `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"addTarget: action:" and "removeTarget: action:" is for all UIControls (like UIButton). There is no way you can use it for UIImages directly.

There are multiple ways to achieve your requirement. (declare a custom UIControl and implement the way you want). But simplest approach is to use UIButton with required images (and background images).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method to action against a button like following:

```
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```